# Can I get group and count in aggregation framework?

Tags: mongodb

I have a score collection like:

```
{grade:1 group:1, alumn:1, score:100},
{grade:1 group:1, alumn:1, score:100},
{grade:1 group:1, alumn:2, score:80},
{grade:1 group:1, alumn:2, score:80},
{grade:1 group:2, alumn:1, score:70},
{grade:1 group:2, alumn:1, score:70},
{grade:1 group:2, alumn:2, score:80},
{grade:1 group:2, alumn:2, score:80},
{grade:1 group:3, alumn:1, score:90},
{grade:1 group:3, alumn:1, score:90},
{grade:1 group:3, alumn:2, score:90},
{grade:1 group:3, alumn:2, score:90},
```

How can I get the best alumn of each grade/group?

grade:1

```
[{group:1, alumn:1, score:200}],
[{group:2, alumn:2, score:160}],
[{group:3, alumn:1, score:180},
 {group:3, alumn:2, score:180}]
```

Comment: No attempt was made to solve the problem.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure aggregation framework supports doing this operation with ties. If a random pick among the alumni sharing the highest score within the group is allowed instead, it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query will return you the output you needed :

```
    var scores = db.scores.aggregate({
    $group: {
        _id: {
            grade: "$grade",
            group: "$group",
            alumn: "$alumn"
        },
        score: {
            $sum: "$score"
        }
    }
    }, {
        $project: {
            _id: 0,
            group: "$_id.group",
            alumn: "$_id.alumn",
            score: "$score"
    }
    }, {
        $sort: {
            group: 1,
            score: -1
    }
});
```

We can't directly get the first document alone, So i have written some JS to do that part:

From the first query, we will get:

```
{
        "result" : [
               {
                        "score" : 200,
                        "group" : 1,
                        "alumn" : 1
                },
                {
                        "score" : 160,
                        "group" : 1,
                        "alumn" : 2
                },
                {
                        "score" : 160,
                        "group" : 2,
                        "alumn" : 2
                },
                {
                        "score" : 140,
                        "group" : 2,
                        "alumn" : 1
                },
                {
                        "score" : 180,
                        "group" : 3,
                        "alumn" : 2
                },
                {
                        "score" : 180,
                        "group" : 3,
                        "alumn" : 1
                }
        ],
        "ok" : 1
}
```

Now comes the filtering part,

```
function duplicate(array,index, value) {
  var matched = false;
  for(var i=0; i<array.length; i++) {
   if(i<index) {
      if(value==array[i].group) {
        return false;
      }
    } else {
     return true;
    }
  }
}
```

Now just call

```
scores.result.filter(function(e,index) {return duplicate(scores.result,index,e.group)});
```

This will give you

```
       [
        {
                "score" : 200,
                "group" : 1,
                "alumn" : 1
        },
        {
                "score" : 160,
                "group" : 2,
                "alumn" : 2
        },
        {
                "score" : 180,
                "group" : 3,
                "alumn" : 2
        }
    ]
```

Comment: Won't this also return `{grade:1 group:1, alumn:2, score:160}` even though he's not the best?

Comment: if you check OP's question, he has only summed the scores. As per the result he wants

Comment: If you read again, you'll notice that he didn't _just_ sum. Group 1 alumn 2 and group 2 alumn 1 were also excluded since they didn't have the highest total scores in their group.

Comment: Ahh yes, will update noe